# No method "getColor" in ColorDrawable in android

Tags: android, eclipse, colors, package

Eclipse gets me very strange error:
The method getColor() is undefined for the type ColorDrawable

```
android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable dd = 
   new android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable();
dd.getColor();
```

I've no idea how to fix it. All other methods are exist. wtf?

Comment: I was facing the same problem and I solved using the solutions proposed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795920/get-background-color-from-textview-without-using-colordrawable-api-11 (not just the accepted solution but also the one of Kiril Aleksandrov)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your target API level? ColorDrawable.getColor() is introduced in API level 11, so if you're targeting a lower API level you won't have access to that function.

Comment: What a terrible situation... so, how to get background color from a button?

Comment: You can pick it out using Java reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Why not draw the Drawable into a tiny offscreen [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html), and call [getPixel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel%28int,%20int%29) to retrieve the colour you drew?