# get background color from textview without using ColorDrawable (API 11)

Tags: android, colors, background, textview

How can i get the backround color of a textview using only API 9?

I basicly want to do this but only using API 9

```
int intID = (ColorDrawable) textView.getBackground().getColor();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this...

```
public static int getBackgroundColor(TextView textView) {
    ColorDrawable drawable = (ColorDrawable) textView.getBackground();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        return drawable.getColor();
    }
    try {
        Field field = drawable.getClass().getDeclaredField("mState");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object object = field.get(drawable);
        field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField("mUseColor");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.getInt(object);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I had to add the @SuppressLint("NewApi") on the methode now that im only using API 9

Comment: Fails on API > 21

Answer (score 3):

Great answer! I just wanted to add that the private field `mState` has two color fields:

- `mUseColor`
- `mBaseColor`

For **getting** the color the above code is great but if you want to **set** the color, you have to set it to the both fields due to problems in `StateListDrawable` instances:

```
    final int color = Color.RED;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        drawable.setColor(color);
    } else {
        try {
            final Field stateField = drawable.getClass().getDeclaredField(
                    "mState");
            stateField.setAccessible(true);
            final Object state = stateField.get(drawable);

            final Field useColorField = state.getClass().getDeclaredField(
                    "mUseColor");
            useColorField.setAccessible(true);
            useColorField.setInt(state, color);

            final Field baseColorField = state.getClass().getDeclaredField(
                    "mBaseColor");
            baseColorField.setAccessible(true);
            baseColorField.setInt(state, color);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot set color to the drawable!");
        }
    }
```

Hope this was helpful! :)